# Prove: if a function in the variable $(\alpha, \beta)$ is greater than or equal to $0$ then so are the limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I'm doing some study and am stuck on this question, ANY help would greatly be appreciated, thanks! :)

**Question**

Assume $g:(\alpha, \beta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function and $\lim_{x\to\alpha+}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\beta-}g(x)$ exist. If $g(x)\geq0$ on $(\alpha, \beta)$, then $\lim_{x\to\alpha+}g(x)\geq0$ and $\lim_{x\to\beta-}g(x)\geq0$. If $g(x)\leq 0$ on $(\alpha, \beta)$, then so are the limits.

**Proof of Attempt**

Fix $\epsilon>0$ then we need to find $\delta>0$ which satisfies $0<|x-a|<\delta$ when $0<|g(x)-l|<\delta$

We know that $\lim_{x\to\alpha+}g(\alpha)$ and $\lim_{x\to\beta-}f(\beta)$ exists

$\therefore 0<|x-\alpha|<\delta$ when $0<|g(\alpha)-l|<\delta$ holds

Assume $g(x)\geq0$, and since it is known $g(x)\neq l$, then $g(\alpha)\geq 0 \implies |g(\alpha)-l|\leq 0$

**Note**

The last line is obviously not 100% correct as $|g(\alpha)-l|<\epsilon$ and $|g(\alpha)-l|\neq\epsilon$ so I think I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Is your function continous?

Comment: @Joe I would assume so

Comment: Since your question is about limits, and you are given that the limits exist, "continuity" is not relevant.

Comment: Assume the limit $l$ to be negative and arrive to a contradiction with positivity (take $\epsilon=|l|/2$ etc)

Comment: I removed the "proof theory" tag - that refers to [a specific subfield of mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory), not general questions about proofs.

Answer (score 0):

The limit at $\alpha$ from the positive direction exists. Let it be $l$. Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta$ so whenever $x-\alpha<\delta$, $\lvert g(x)-l\rvert<\epsilon$.

Suppose $l<0$, and take $0<\epsilon<-l$, so $\epsilon+l<0$. But then there is a $\delta$ so that
$$ x-\alpha<\delta \implies \lvert g(x)-l\rvert<\epsilon. $$
But the latter means that there is certainly one $x$ with $g(x)<l+\epsilon<0$, contradicting that $g(x)>0$ for $x \in (\alpha,\beta)$.

The rest are done similarly: the key is to use the limit having the wrong sign to force an internal point with the wrong sign to exist.

Answer (score 0):

If by contradiction $\lim_{x\to\alpha^+}g(x)=l<0$, then fixed $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\alpha<x<\alpha+\delta\;\Rightarrow |g(x)-l|<\epsilon
$$
but
\begin{align*}
|g(x)-l|<\epsilon
&\Longleftrightarrow -\epsilon<g(x)-l<\epsilon\\
&\Longleftrightarrow -\epsilon+l<g(x)<l+\epsilon
\end{align*}
In particular, chosing $\epsilon=|l|/2$ we have that $l+\epsilon<0$ thus $g$ wouldn't be $\ge0$ on $]\alpha,\beta[$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple question and one should try to think of it as a simple problem only. Using $\epsilon-\delta$ is just going to complicate matters unnecessarily. I hope you understand the definition of limit at some level and you are convinced of the truth of the following fact:

*If $L$ is the limit of $f(x) $ as $x\to a$ then it means that we get the values of $f$ as close to $L$ as we want.*

And combine this with the highly obvious following fact:

*If $A$ is a non zero real numbers then there there is a neighborhood a of $A$ whose members have the same sign as that of $A$. In other words if we get too close to $A$ we will get numbers whose sign is same as that of $A$.*

Do you see how to get a solution to your problem? Your function is non-negative.  Suppose that it's limit is negative. Since the values of the function can be as close to the limit as we want, ultimately we must get negative values of the function. And we are done with the contradiction.